# Sending HTML in e-mail

Tags: c#, .net, html-email, embedding

I need my .NET desktop app to be able to send various HTML mails, allowing users to create custom templates, including images and possibly CSS style (if they copy/paste the HTML from other sources).

From what I've been reading, it's not that simple:

- Images need to be embedded and their links replaced with content IDs
- CSS styles containing images also need to be fixed
- Background color/image won't work, it's better to wrap the mail in a table and apply the CSS to it
- SMTP servers can interpret lines starting with a dot as "end of transmission", so at least a space must be added to all such lines
- Who knows what else

My questions are:

1. Is there anything else I should take care of?
2. Is there a library which already does this so that I don't reinvent?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One thing I can think of, make use of [Alternate views](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.alternateviews.aspx) for those recipients whose mail clients can't/won't accept HTML emails (or they've got it turned off). That way they'll get a plain text version, in which you could include a link to an html version live on the web if they decide want to view it.

I have also heard that not including a plain text version increases your likelyhood of being marked as spam - this is due to the fact that many mail filters compare the plain text and html versions of a message; if they differ too wildly it's not a good sign for you :-)

Other spam indicators include html messages which have more pictures than text, and generally sloppy html - broken css, bad links, missing tags etc - consider using some sort of markup validator before sending.

Comment: Im one of those who would complain if it came with no straight text, because if I read it using elm and all I get is html, I tend not to read it :)

Answer (score 0):

I have found the following CodeProject article, which describes how to embed various image resources into the mail:

- [Sending the contents of a webpage with images as an HTML mail](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16873/Sending-the-contents-of-a-webpage-with-images-as-a).

It has some useful examples, although it doesn't seem to include an alternate plain text view, so I will have to add that.

It's still a pity that no-one has put together a library which does this stuff automatically.